# not able to create the p element as justified in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

currently working on 
graphotic.com

these are four section on home page....(these are posts)

1. Branding
2. Graphic Design
3. Packaging
4. Printing

and using the php the_excerpt() function;

In the theme, this php line is responsible to display the content from the post, with read more link....

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Read More>></a>
```

now the the issue is; i want to justify the excerpt content, but i am not able to find the `<p>` sothat i can put align=justify..

please help

Answer (score 0):

`the_excerpt();` will output paragraph tags. Trying to wrap the function in paragraph tags will result in invalid markup and the styling won't work.

Use a `div` tag instead:

```
<div class="post-excerpt">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div style="text-align: justify;">
```

Remember to add a rule to your stylesheet for the first option. As other users have already pointed out the second option isn't considered best practice.

```
.post-excerpt {
    text-align: justify;
}
```